# Find how many times a string appears within elements of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list of strings such as this:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Darren"]
```

How would I find how many of these strings contain the letter 'a'?

I tried using the count function

```
names.count("a")
```

But this only output the amount of elements that **were** 'a' rather than **contained** 'a'.

Comment: You need to iterate over your list, and count if an item contains an 'a'

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can be used to determine the no. of elements with letter `'a'` in them.

```py
print(len([x for x in names if 'a' in x]))
```

O/P: `2`

Comment: what's "O/P: 2" ?

Comment: O/P is short for Output.

Comment: The suggestion in your note will not save any memory, and likely give a `NameError` unless `_` has been defined somewhere.

Comment: @Jasmijn Thank you for the memory part. As for _, it won't give NameError as in python 3.11, that I am using.

Comment: @Sam It depends on if `_` is defined. In the REPL, it's automatically bound to the last evaluated expression. If you start a fresh REPL and only enter the lines `names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Darren"]` and `print(len([_ for x in names if 'a' in x]))`, you'll get the name error. See [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python/5893946#5893946).

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `loop`:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Darren"]

count=0

for i in range(len(names)):
    if 'a' in list(names[i]):
        count+=1
        
print(count)
```

Output:

```
>>> 2
```

Comment: Iterate over items, not with a range, don"t convert each item to a list, that useless

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you want to count how many elements in a list satisfy a condition, you have to *iterate* the list, that is, check the condition for every element and count successful tries:

```
names = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Darren"]
count = 0

for name in names:
    if 'a' in name:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

On a more advanced note, recall that boolean values (like `a in b`) are actually integers in Python and that there's a built-in `sum` function to which you can pass a generator expression. Combining these ideas, the solution is as simple as:

```
print(sum('a' in name for name in names))
```